# How to run OpenOffice and pass a document to it?

Tags: command-line, openoffice, command-line-arguments, openoffice-writer

I want to open xyz.txt file in Open Office Writer from Windows command line. 
The [manual](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Framework/Article/Command_Line_Arguments) show only the command for opening the file in read only mode. But I want to open it in Edit mode.

> c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\swriter.exe -view
>   "xyz.txt"

Comment: Solved: the command is -o. I was mislead by the way they explained that parameter in the manual. However, there is a problem. Instead of simply opening the document, OpenOffice shows firstly the 'ASCII filter option' dialog, and then the actual document.

Comment: In fact you don't need any options at all: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\swriter.exe" "xyz.txt"` will open the document, and it will be in view mode only if it's read-only.